# Sump Discharge Options - Storm Sewer or Dry Well

Tags: drainage, french-drain, sump

Today, my sump discharges out a flex hose for about 30 feet into my backyard. This works fine and there isn't any pooling of water, even during heavy rainstorms. Rather than removing the flex hose each winter when the pump isn't running, I'd like to have a permanent discharge mechanism in place.

As far as I can tell this means changing the discharge hose to some sort of PVC and burying it below the frost line and discharging to a dry well. Interestingly, there is a storm sewer 'beehive' on my property line with my neighbor. I'm wondering if rather than building a dry well in my already small yard (under 10k sq ft), I could simply have the discharge go straight into the storm sewer or if the dry well is really the best/only way to go. I'm in northern IL, so it does get cold here during the winter (sometimes -20 air temp), so the frost line I believe is around 48" but maybe I wouldn't need to dig that deep?

Comment: Check your local regulations -- some local codes don't permit sump pumps to discharge to municipal sewers (storm or sanitary).  Or is this "beehive" part of a private drainage system?

Comment: Said 'beehive' is the city's storm sewer system. I'll definitely be sure to check with them.

Comment: Just reviewed a city flyer on sump pump drainage. It's a big 'no' for draining to sanitary sewer (they too say a dry well or rain garden is the way to go) but they do not say 'no' to storm water detention basins/sewers.